# How to do iterative joins in plyr

Tags: r, join, plyr

Consider the following code:

```
df_a <- df_b <- df_c <- df_d <- expand.grid(AA=1:20, BB=1:20) 
n <- dim(df_a)[1]
df_a$A <- runif(n)
df_b$B <- runif(n)
df_c$C <- runif(n)
df_d$D <- runif(n)

df_a <- df_a[sample(1:n, replace=TRUE),]  
df_b <- df_b[sample(1:n, replace=TRUE),]  
df_c <- df_c[sample(1:n, replace=TRUE),]  
df_d <- df_d[sample(1:n, replace=TRUE),]  

require(plyr)

df_combined <- join(x=df_a, y=df_b)
df_combined <- join(x=df_combined, y=df_c)
df_combined <- join(x=df_combined, y=df_d)
```

What would be a good way of creating `df_combined` using the split-apply-combine paradigm? Of course once `df_combined` has been created from the first join I could then use a for loop to pass it the later objects. But this requires that the object `df_combined` first exists outside of the loop, meaning the code cannot then be easily vectorised.

Is there a way, for example, of, for each piece that `plyr` divides an object into, referencing the previous or subsequent pieces within a function?

Comment: `library(dplyr);df_combined <- left_join(df_a, df_b) %>% left_join(df_c) %>% left_join(df_d)`

Comment: Thanks - I know the dplyr version too. But what I was after was a general solution that could work for any number of objects. The Reduce function suggested below looks like it does just this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to repeatedly join data together is to use `Reduce`. It isn't part of the same family of packages as `plyr`, but it is a more general way to repeatedly apply a binary function to a list of elements. In your case, you could do:

```
df_combined <- Reduce(join, list(df_a, df_b, df_c, df_d))
```

Beware, however, that this won't be much faster (for the computer) to run. Indeed, the heart of `Reduce` is just a `for` loop. But I find the syntax to be clean.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of this. Looks just what I was after. Really I was just after a cleaner looking and generalisable syntax rather than thinking about computational efficiency, so this fits the bill.